# How do you stop a Thread when the Activity it was started in is left?

Tags: android, onpause, onbackpressed

I have looked at `onBackPressed()`, `onPause()`, and `onStop()` but the biggest issue I can find against these is that my `Thread` isn't declared in the `Activity`. I have `MainActivity` and `TiltActivity`. There is a `Button` that, when pressed, sends you from `MainActivity` to `TiltActivity`. Once inside of `TiltActivity` I create an object of the class `TCP_IP_Client`. I then start a 'Thread' that is declared inside of `TCP_IP_Client`.

I can't pass a `Thread` parameter to `onBackPressed()`, `onPause()`, or`onStop()`. How do I stop the `Thread` once `TiltActivity` is left if I can't interrupt it in the previous overridden functions. Again, the `Thread` is not declared in `TiltActivity` which would make it much easier to interrupt the `Thread`. If you need further clarification please let me know.

Comment: cant you just keep a reference to it and stop the thread in the onPause/onStop function?

Comment: You can't pass the reference to the function. `public void onPause(Thread t)` isn't a thing sadly.

Comment: make it a field in your activity and set it in onCreate, then you can access it in onPause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a method to TCP_IP_Client that will stop the thread that it declared and started.  You then can call that method on your instance of TCP_IP_Client from your TitleActivity (using your member variable that holds the TCP_IP_Client instance).

Comment: I will try this on Monday and let you know how it goes. This sounds like a nice and simple fix that I really should have thought of. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is supposing you have some kind of loop in the `Thread`.
In the `TiltActivity` you define an attribute to hold a reference to the `Thread` and a shared `boolean` to let it know it should stop.
And you provide synchronized methods for accessing the shared variables.

In `onResume()` you create and start the `Thread` so it gets recreated each time you enter the activity. And in `onPause()` you signal it to stop and interrupt it each time it is about to be taken away from the foreground;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ThreadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = ThreadActivity.class.getName();

    boolean stopThread = false;
    Thread t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startTheThread();
    }

    public synchronized boolean continueRunning(){
        return !stopThread;
    }

    public synchronized void startTheThread(){
        this.stopThread = false;
        Toast.makeText(ThreadActivity.this,"Thread Starting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(continueRunning()){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ThreadActivity.this,"Thread running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        ;//do nothing
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
    public synchronized void stopTheThread(){
        this.stopThread = true;
        t.interrupt();
        Toast.makeText(ThreadActivity.this,"Thread stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopTheThread();

    }
}
```